# Which is the best practice for maintaining and distributing one assembly code base for both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.6

Tags: c#

We distribute a .NET 3.5 assembly to more parties to be referenced and used in different applications.

We are now intending to upgrade this assembly to .NET 4.6 so it will benefit of all performance and security *improvements in this .NET version* and *not for using new .NET features*.

But we don't want to break existing applications that are using it.

Some consumer applications might still be using .NET 3.5 so they won't be able to use it, so I was thinking how about having two projects targeting two .NET versions (3.5 and 4.6), but same code files.

**What would you recommend for maintaining and distributing one assembly code base for both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.6 version lines?**

Later Edit: This question is not about referencing a .NET 4.6 assembly in .NET 3.5, it's about how can a .NET 4.6 application to use my assembly and benefit of the security and performance of .NET 4.6 while running it. The 3.5 apps should continue to use my 3.5 assembly.

Comment: You cant make something forwards compatible...You'll need to ship two versions or get your clients to upgrade

Comment: Yes, this is what I was suggesting: shipping two versions. But which is the best practice in doing so? Should I have two projects targeting different .NET framework?

Comment: You can't use 4.5 features in a 3.5 assembly. So you need two **completely** different versions!

Comment: @Liam, I don't want to use .NET 4.5 features in 3.5 assembly. The two .NET version lines are parallel and distributed separately. What I want is to benefit of the performance improvements in .NET 4.5 while ensuring I don't write code that doesn't work in .NET 3.5.

Comment: why bother upgrading then? You gain nothing

Comment: When my previous company did this we kept two solutions, the .NET 3.5 files were all just linked files to the .NET 4.0+ files with any code differences made in a file of the same name. It's tough to keep 2 different versions and I wouldn't suggest it.

Comment: I gain performance and security improvements in .NET 4.6, but only for customers using  .NET 4.6.

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that .Net is built on previous versions. .Net 4.6 contains .Net 3.5. If your not using any new methods, etc. then you might as well just use 3.5. If it wasn't built like this is wouldn't be **backwards** compatible.

Comment: Liam, I am sorry, but .NET 4.6 does not replace .NET 3.5, these are separate installations. The two version lines can be installed, uninstalled separately.

Comment: I never said that I said .Net4.6 **contains** all the code that .Net3.5 does, as is, no changes, no performance benefits, no extra security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into creating your own nuget repository and publish the libraries in each specific version of .net needed. (For one package can have varying .net versions as needed).

Once in your nuget repository they have their own version and can be updated either in lockstep or differently.  That way the consumers can use the target version as needed for the target .net version.

See [Hosting Your Own NuGet Feeds](http://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds)

Comment: That's actually a very good idea, thanks OmegaMan. The only problem is that all consumers will need to have access to the repository and the assembly is kind of a private one.

Comment: @Kosmo We started doing it in house and have different nuget package servers depending on the company division and within those servers their are different sub packages which speak to many different  projects. Very flexible and works well with version control for the consumers.

Comment: do you have any suggestion o how to make sure we are not accidentally using .NET 4.6.0 features in the code, but still targeting .NET 4.6.0. I was thinking to use two projects with different target framework but same code base.

Comment: @Kosmo pragma defines to separate out the code depending on .net version currently being compiled. [#pragma (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x74w198a.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There seem's to be an assumption that an identical code base compiled in .Net 4.6 will gain *"performance and security"*. **This isn't true**. If the codebase is identical it will perform identically and the security will be the same.

Each iteration of .Net contains the previous one (it's actually a monolythic process that Microsoft are trying to move away from, hence projects such as [Katana](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana))

> Each new version of the .NET Framework retains features from the
>   previous versions and adds new features.

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx)

Simply upgrading the framework will not magically make you code faster or more secure.

Answer (score 1):

At a previous company we used to do as you are suggesting and ship a .NET 3.5 version (for users on XP) and a .NET 4.0+ (up to 4.5) version.

The way we did this was to have two separate solutions basically called the same and have each of the projects mirrored from the .NET 4.0 version into the 3.5 version. These were actual projects added to the solution.

For the files we simply linked the .NET 4.0 files directly into these projects, but we did have to manually create each folder so that the namespaces matched. For any code that was not supported by .NET 3.5 we had to create an actual file in the 3.5 solution and re-write entirely that feature so that it would compile with 3.5.

This was not fun and actually wasted a lot of development time simply looking after a legacy solution. In the end we migrated everything to .NET 4.5 and expressed to users that we were discontinuing support for the 3.5 version, for us there was not cost for the user to upgrade so it was up to them if they wished to upgrade hardware for new functionality.

In conclusion I would say if you don't need to I would recommend that you don't attempt to support both solutions, it will impact your development time and frustrate developers when they've written this nice feature using the concurrent functionality to then realize this isn't in .NET 3.5 (I know what this is like because I've had it happen).